# Elasticsearch Bulk Index - Update only if exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using [Elasticsearch Bulk Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) to update some stats of a documents, but it may happen the document I am trying to update does not exist - in this case I want it to do nothing.

**I don't want it to create the document in this case.**

I haven't found anything in the docs, or perhaps missed it.

My current actions (In this case it creates the document):

```
{
    update: {
        _index: "index1",
        _type: "interaction",
        _id: item.id
    }
},
{
    script: {
        file: "update-stats",
        lang: "groovy",
        params: {
            newCommentsCount: newRetweetCount,
        }
    },
    upsert: normalizedItem
}
```

How do I update the document only if it exists, otherwise nothing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use upsert and use a normal update.
Also if the document does not exist while updating , the update will fail. 
There by it should work well for you.

Comment: The update without an upsert clause will fail and create an exception. If an application, by design, requires this update-only-if-exists functionality, then many exceptions will be thrown this way. Given some SO Q&A point to how slow exceptions are, doesn't this solution cause performance concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me with elasticsearch 7.15.2 (need to check lowest supported version for this, ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#update-api-example)

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/exp/_update/8' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '
{
  "scripted_upsert": true,
  "script": {
    "source": "if ( ctx.op == \"create\" )  {ctx.op=\"noop\"} else  {ctx._source.name=\"updatedName\"} ",
    "params": {
      "count": 4
    }
  },
  "upsert": {}
}

'
```

If ES is about to create a new record (ctx.op is "create" then we change the op to "noop" and nothing is done, otherwise we do the normal update through the script.